# Laravel 8.8 redirectTo function does't work

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-8, middleware

I need to implement logic when authorizing a user and I planned to do this in the `redirectTo()` function in the `LoginController`. However, Laravel does not seem to see it and always redirects to the HOME constant.

It seems that all files are correct.

##### LoginController

```php
protected function redirectTo()
{

    return redirect('/test');
}
```

##### auth-backend/RedirectsUsers

```php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

    foreach ($guards as $guard) {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/account');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Some users have found that the redirect happens in the `middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated`, but I don't know how to fix it. If in this file I replace return `redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME)` with some path, for example `redirect('/account')` then it returns `/account`. But I still need to be in the `redirectTo()` function.

##### Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated

```php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

    foreach ($guards as $guard) {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/account');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

How can I make the process come to `redirectTo()` after authorization?

Comment: what package did you install to get a `LoginController`?

Comment: laravel/ui, then I run php artisan ui/auth

Comment: what logic are you trying to add to the authentication process?

Comment: users have different roles and also it should be like a personal account with your own link, something like posts and customized data in it and I saw the realization of such thing via redirectTo and then Policy settings for users. Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score -1):

1. Define a route in **web.php** for redirectTo function in Login Controller

   Route::get('check-auth', [LoginController::class, 'redirectTo'])->name('auth.redirect-to');
2. return to the route

   return redirect()->route('auth.redirect-to');

make sure to use the LoginController on the top of web.php